# What does .data stand for?

Tags: jquery

```
var linkVar = { message:'Hello from a link'};
var pVar = { message:'Hello from a paragraph'};
function showMessage(evt) {
 alert(evt.data.message);
}
$('a').bind('click',linkVar,showMessage);
$('p').bind('mouseover',pVar,showMessage);
```

Well, I know how the bind() function works. What I can't understand is the following part:

```
alert(evt.data.message);
```

Where does this .data function (or whatever it is) come from? Is that just a standard way of referring to the object's message property?

Answer (score 3):

jQuery's `bind()` should be replaced by `on()` now, but in this case it doesn't really matter, the arguments are the same

```
.bind( eventType [, eventData ], handler )
```

the `eventData` argument is optional, and just passes data to the callback, just as your example shows it does.

This is jQuery specific, and something that's added to the way `bind`/`on` works, to be able to pass data to the callback.

It's not used very often, but it comes in handy to be able to pass static data to the callback function at times.

Here's another example

```
$(element).on('click', {optional : 'data'}, function(e) {

   console.log( e.data.optional ); // outputs "data"

});
```

Comment: Thank you  very much for a quick answer. By the way, why should bind () be replaced by on()? I'm just learning events in jQuery so, I guess, it might be useful for me to know that.

Comment: `on` has replaced `bind` as the preferred method for event binding. If you look at the [documentation for `bind`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/), the first sentence is *"As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method is the preferred method for attaching event handlers to a document."*

Comment: I was referring to and old edition of the book that I use to learn jQuery. Just checked out the latest one - there the author notes that bind(), as well as live() and delegate(),  have been replaced by on() and unbind() - by off(). Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Yeap, it is a part of eventInfo object going from bind callback. There you can see the same :

http://api.jquery.com/bind/

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From the jQuery documetnation for [bind()](http://api.jquery.com/bind/#bind-eventType-eventData-handler)

> ### `.bind( eventType [, eventData ] [, preventBubble ] )`
>
> **eventType** Type: String
>
> A string containing one or more DOM event types, such as
>   "click" or "submit," or custom event names.
>
> **eventData** Type: Anything
>
> An object containing data that will be passed to the event handler.
>
> **preventBubble** Type: Boolean
>
> Setting the third argument to false will
>   attach a function that prevents the default action from occurring and
>   stops the event from bubbling. The default is true.

So when you pass in data to the bind method (second parameter) it is available on the event object as a [data property](https://api.jquery.com/event.data/).

> ### `event.data`
>
> Description: An optional object of data passed to an event method when the current executing handler is bound.